# DWScript: exposing and returning an object to script from Delphi function?

Tags: delphi, dwscript

In my Delphi (2010) code I have a class TImageItem, which I have exposed to DWScript via:

```
dwsUnit.ExposeRTTI(TypeInfo(TImageItem),[eoNoFreeOnCleanup, eoExposePublic]);
```

In dwsUnit I have declared a function to get a TImageItem from the Delphi side:

```
function GetImage: TImageItem;
```

and on the Delphi side:

```
procedure TFScript.dwsUnitFunctionsGetImageEval(info: TProgramInfo);
begin
    ...
    // (Item is a TImageItem and not nil)
    Info.ResultAsVariant := TdwsRTTIVariant.FromObject(Item);
end;
```

However, when I run a script starting like:

```
var Item: TImageItem;
Item := GetImage;
...
```

I get an EScriptError during the GetImage call with the message "Object already destroyed".

What am I doing wrong? Am I exposing the object or returning it incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about `ExposeRTTI`, as I've never used it, but I would do it like this:

```
procedure TFScript.dwsUnitFunctionsGetImageEval(info: TProgramInfo);
begin
  ...
  // (Item is a TImageItem and not nil)
  Info.ResultAsVariant := Info.Vars[Info.ResultVars.TypeSym.Name].GetConstructor('Create', Item).Call.Value;
end;
```